# Can I watch Gunslinger Girls S1 + S2 and then read from volume 6?

Tags: gunslinger-girl

I hear S1 mostly is faithful, but I don't know much about S2 (which I also hear is worse than S1). Would I be missing out anything if I watch S1 and S2 then read from where the anime ends?

Comment: Related: [Difference Between the Anime and Manga for Gunslinger Girl?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7626/2516)

Comment: S2 is much worse than S1. You're not wrong there.

Comment: S2 is worse than S1, but that is because it follows the manga closely and the manga gets worse and worse as time goes on. Though, in the manga it isn't that jarring since the character design remains mostly consistent, but going from S1 to S2 it is like you are watching a different show.

Answer (score 1):

I only know the manga, but based on searching around and [episode titles](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUNSLINGER_GIRL#%E7%AC%AC2%E6%9C%9F) of S2, most probably you can continue from volume 6 after watching S2. Possible usual difference of anime/manga aside (the link mentions a diff of characters' phrases), you wouldn't lose much that way.

Note also seemingly there are 2 extra episodes which were not on air (marked as OVA in the above link).

---

[This website](http://wikis.sakura.ne.jp/gsg/?%A5%A2%A5%CB%A5%E1%C2%E8%A3%B1%B4%FC) gives the correspondence of original/anime for S1.